# pyspark.zip not found,Application application_1558064260263_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

```
 The YARN application has already ended! It might have been killed or the Application Master may have failed to start. Check the YARN application logs for more details.
```

```
19/05/17 10:11:06 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
19/05/17 10:11:06 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
19/05/17 10:11:06 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/05/17 10:11:06 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
19/05/17 10:11:10 ERROR YarnClientSchedulerBackend: The YARN application has already ended! It might have been killed or the Application Master may have failed to start. Check the YARN application logs for more details.
19/05/17 10:11:10 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1558064260263_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1558064260263_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2019-05-17 10:11:09.626]File file:/home/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1558064260263_0002/pyspark.zip does not exist
```

```
19/05/17 10:11:06 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
19/05/17 10:11:06 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
19/05/17 10:11:06 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
19/05/17 10:11:06 WARN Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.

19/05/17 10:11:10 ERROR YarnClientSchedulerBackend: The YARN application has already ended! It might have been killed or the Application Master may have failed to start. Check the YARN application logs for more details.
19/05/17 10:11:10 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
```

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1558064260263_0002 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1558064260263_0002_000002 exited with  exitCode: -1000

Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2019-05-17 10:11:09.626]File file:/home/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1558064260263_0002/pyspark.zip does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add these lines in your .bashrc**

```
function snotebook ()
{
#Spark path (based on your computer)
SPARK_PATH=$SPARK_HOME

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"

# For python 3 users, you have to add the line below or you will get an error 
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/anaconda3/bin/python

$SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master yarn
}

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export YARN_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
```